# why p:remote command update="@none" renders other forms components?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

I want to make a timeout mechanism for a defined login period to my project. If users make the system wait on idle mode, after a while I want to generate some action on the system for automatic logout.

I have a remoteCommand component in the template page like base.xhtml in a form. I want it to render just its own form.However, it renders all components and forms in the page.

Here's my code:

```
<h:form id="formIdle">
    <p:remoteCommand  id="rcActive" name="rcActive"  action="#{editorApplication.onUserActivity}"
                      process="@this" update="@none"/>
</h:form>
```

Note: Please do not suggest IdleMonitor, I tried it and not solved my problem because of project requirements.

Comment: i know @none should work but try «this instead anyway. If it's not working please provide more code.

Comment: Yes, post an [mcve] (see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). My best guess... nested forms

Comment: How/Where are you invoking ths `rcActive` JS method?

Comment: How do you verify, "*It renders all components and forms in the page*"? Just list the desired components to be updated in the `update` attribute of `<p:remoteCommand>`.

Comment: @Tiny: Read the question more carefully. OP does not want to update any component, hence the `update="@none"`

Comment: @Kukeltje : Linguistic sense of "***I want it to render just its own form.** However, it renders all components and forms in the page.*" clearly implies that the only form in which the `<p:remoteCommand>` resides is expected to be rendered but it somehow unknowingly renders everything functioning like `update="@all"`.  Whether `update="@none"` is specified with that `<p:remoteCommand>` or not is then a story apart. It does not match with the English sense of those two sentences. All in all, honestly and frankly, it is the fault of the poster's and not our's :)

Comment: OOOPS... You are right... it contradicts... and **certainly** not our fault :). More indirect 'proof' of nested forms imo

Comment: 1) Forms are not nested.
2) There are 3 forms in the page wich are INDEPENDENT.
3) One form includes remote command.
4) Remote command has attribute update="@none". 
5) Remote command tries to update all forms in the page, as the topic of this question mentions...

5 is the problem.

Clear now ? :)